# Login database issues

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to fill a database with records so that when you login it will either accept you or not. For now I just have one to test it out but it doesn't seem to work. When I put in the info for ID and password and click the Button, nothing happens. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong? Sorry if it's obvious, but I'm just stuck right now.

https://github.com/liliycode/Login/blob/master/login%20java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click listener is not correct. You should define click listener for button in onCreate method. When you click button you get data from `edittext` and invoke method which inserts data to DB.

Comment: Thank you both, I have my problem fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your are comparing EditTexts to strings which is wrong

```
if ( loginET.equals("Liliy") && login2ET.equals("1234"))
```

change this to

```
 if ( loginET.getText().toString().equals("Liliy") && login2ET.getText().toString().equals("1234"))
```

And make your buttonListener in `onCreate()`, and at click of button call your method `populateData()`

```
pressBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //reading the inputs
                String idET = loginET.getText().toString();
                Double passET = Double.parseDouble(login2ET.getText().toString());
            populateData();
            }
        });
```

Which checks for data and populates it.